# What is the Ubuntu installer called?

Tags: source-code

This may be a stupid question, but I want to check the source code of the default Ubuntu installer program . I can't seem to find it, and I assume it is easier if I know the name of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "Ubiquity".

You can find the source code on the [Launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/ubiquity) or download the release used in your Ubuntu version using

```
apt-get source ubiquity
```

Comment: Also, if you want the source so you can contribute rather than just examine, there's [an alternate method of getting the source using `bzr` on the development page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Installer/Development#Revision_Control).